# Get the middle scoped value of variable

Tags: c++

Say this is an chunk of code to demonstrate how to use local and global variables. I was trying to explain this to one junior guy and he asked me this question.

In the below code, what should you do to get the value of 'x' from outer loop. In this case, how to access 'x' which has its value as 2.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int x = 1;
void fun() {
  int x = 2;
  {
    int x = 3;
    cout << x << endl; // This will give 3
    cout << ::x << endl; // This will give 1
    // What should I write here to get x = 2.
  }
}
int main() {
  fun();
}
```

Comment: You can't. Rename one of the variables.

Comment: Why  make life difficult and code unreadable? Having multiple variables with the same name will make errors  more  likely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The name of the first `x` has been hidden by the second `x`. Since the first `x` does not belong to a namespace (including the global namespace), class or enum, you cannot qualify its name, so it is inaccessible.